# Is there a connection between The Master and MODUS?

Tags: fallout-series

I've been playing Fallout76, and I've recently finished the quest line "[One of us](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/One_of_Us)".
While completing this quest, I've had the distinct feeling that I had encountered MODUS before.

After thinking about it for a while, I think it's because the way MODUS talks and emotes, reminds me heavily of The Master from the original fallout.

Is there some link between the two?
If not, is there another similar character in the fallout universe?

Comment: I don't think there is a link, maybe they just have a templated bad-guy they change per game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing the [Wikia article on MODUS](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/MODUS) I can confirm there is not a direct connection between the Master and MODUS. While they do have similar mannerisms there isn't any relation between the two. The most similar character is [President John Henry Eden](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/John_Henry_Eden), but there the only significant relation is they're both part of the Enclave faction and they're both an artificial intelligence.

It seems that MODUS is pretty much independent from most of the Fallout lore

Comment: This is one question I completely forgot about! Thanks for the answer, back when I posed the question the game was just released and the wikia was not as extensive :)

Comment: If you believe this post answers your question don't forget to mark it as accepted